# High speed photodiode for laser pulse width measurement

Tags: photodiode

I want to measure the temporal width of a Q-Switched laser (which should be close to 5 ns) and the delay between two lasers that I send in my experiment. The delay is between 1 ns and 1 µs. Wavelength will be in the visible.

I'm not sure about the device that I have to use. I found the FDS025 photodiode from Thorlabs (low capacitance 0.94 pF and rise/fall time of 47/226 ps but with small area, only 0.049 mm²). Is it sufficient? Since I'm looking directly at the laser, should I suffer from the low current generated by the PD? If yes, what kind of high-speed amplifier do I have to use?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is the lowest power per square metre that might illuminate the PD? What is the amps/watt for the PD in the data sheet?

Comment: I don't know exactly for the lowest power per square but I guess it will be about 3 10 mJ for a spot size of 1 cm. The responsivity of the PD is 0.48 A/W

Answer (score 1):

3 to 10 µJ / 5 ns = average power of 600-2000 W.

Spot size 1 cm vs. detector size of 0.049 mm<sup>2</sup> means that the detector is intercepting about 1/1600 of this power, or about 0.375 to 1.25 W.

This gives a current of 0.375 to 1.25 W * 0.48A/W = 0.18 to 0.6 A

This will charge 0.94 pF at a rate of 0.18 to 0.6 A / 0.94 pF = 0.19 to 0.64 V/ps. Of course, the overall capacitance of your test setup will be at least an order of magnitude higher.

Comment: Yes, something is wrong in my answer, it's 3-10 (3 to 10) instead of 310 ! And it's µJ instead of mJ sorry for this.

Comment: OK, I've adjusted the numbers in my answer. Seems to be consistent with the specs.

Comment: Thank you for help Dave. What did you mean by the overall capitance ? You talk about the capacitance of oscilloscope ? If i put a 50 Ohm load resitance at the end of the PD, 0.19 to 0.64 V/ps will be enough to avoid the use of operational amplifier ?

Comment: The capacitance of the wiring, the test fixture, and the input of whatever buffer you're using to drive the scope cable.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Hamamatsu products. [S5973](https://www.hamamatsu.com/eu/en/product/type/S5973-02/index.html) is available from Farnell and other suppliers, and cost is reasonable. They also have some interesting app notes on preamps and so on if you look around their site (you will surely need one).